# How to get parse tree in ANTLRWorks 2?

Tags: interpreter, antlr4, antlrworks, parse-tree

I am currently using ANTLRWorks 2. I don't know how to interpret example in it. In ANTLRWorks-1.5.2 there is an interpreter tab that you can paste your example. Is there something like that in ANTLRWorks 2? How you can get parse tree for input? Does input have to be in a specific file? 
BTW, I couldn't get any result by using Run->Run in TestRig and uploading any input file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How you can get parse tree for input?

The way you already tried: <kbd>Run</kbd> → <kbd>Run in TestRig</kbd>

> Does input have to be in a specific file?

Yes.

> BTW, I couldn't get any result by using Run->Run in TestRig and uploading any input file.

Then you probably did something wrong. Incorrect input file? Incorrect start rule? Pretty hard to say, really.

There's also [the ANTLR4 plugin for IntelliJ](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7358?pr=) which does interpreting on the fly and produces the parse tree. Also a very nice tool!

Comment: Again thanks for your help, I have one more question about input file, it needs specific format? Is there any document for ANTLRWorks 2, to help me how to work with that?

Comment: No, it just needs to contain the input your grammar expects (and if that isn't the case, some parsing error will occur).

Comment: You are indeed correct, my start rule was wrong. Works like a charm now, thanks :)